# How to let Pytest not catch Exceptions

Tags: python, exception, pytest

Pytest catches exceptions in order to know which tests pass and with fail.

In order to run my tests inside any IDE I usually add sth. like this to my test script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()
```

This way I can run my tests like any other script while PyTest specific stuff like `fixture`s and `parametrize`d functions still work.

But now exceptions (`AssertionError` in particular) are being catched by PyTest and won't let the debugger break for further investigation..

Is there a way to make PyTest not catch exceptions?

Comment: How exactly does pylint catch the assertion errors, can you give an example? Pylint is a code checker and is not supposed to interfere at runtime.

Comment: Sorry - wrote Pylint but i meant PyTest

Comment: I think the `--pdb` option is what you are looking for: `pytest.main(['--pdb'])`. When provided, `pytest` will drop to the debugger when an unhandled error is raised in test body. You can also provide a custom debugger impl - this is what decent IDEs usually do (confirmed with PyCharm and Wing IDE). If yours does not, check what debugger it uses and configure the `pytest` invocation so the debugger is passed via `pdbcls` arg.

Comment: This sounds very promising - why don't you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @hoefling Can you elaborate on how to pass the Pycharm debugger into pdb?